# Symfony2 Doctrine custom types generating unneeded migrations

Tags: symfony, types, doctrine-orm

I have created a custom doctrine type as told in http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html

Here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace XXX\Bundle\XXXBundle\Doctrine\Type;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType;

class UTCDateTimeType extends DateTimeType
{
    static private $utc = null;

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }

        $value->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $dbDate = $value->format($platform->getDateTimeFormatString());

        return $dbDate;
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }

        $val = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
            $platform->getDateTimeFormatString(),
            $value,
            (self::$utc) ? self::$utc : (self::$utc = new \DateTimeZone('UTC'))
        );
        if (!$val) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailed($value, $this->getName());
        }
        return $val;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run `app/console doctrine:migrations:diff` it always will generate new migrations even if I have migrated, and the content is always the same. Example:

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE Availability CHANGE start start DATETIME NOT NULL, CHANGE end end DATETIME NOT NULL, CHANGE rrule rrule LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE created created DATETIME NOT NULL, CHANGE updated updated DATETIME NOT NULL');
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a response from Steve Müller from this bug report : http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-1085

> I think you will have to mark your custom type as requiring a SQL
>   comment, otherwise the schema manager cannot distinguish between
>   DateTime type and your custom type because both map to the same native
>   SQL type.
>
> See here:
>   https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/Type.php#L327-L340
>
> You will have to add the following to your custom type implementation:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * {@inheritdoc}
>  */
> public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
> {
>     return true;
> }
> ```
>
> Also I think it might be required to give your custom type a distinct name like:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * {@inheritdoc}
>  */
> public function getName()
> {
>     return 'datetime_utc';
> }
> ```

There features are implemented in doctrine >=2.3

Comment: Note: adding `requiresSQLCommentHint` won't solve the problem automatically. `Diff` will ignore the change. **You will have to add the comment manually.** I created a ticket for this: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-1193

Comment: @vbence link is broken do you know if that bug is fixed?

Comment: @vence how can I "add the comment manually"? I mean, which text I have to put in the comment?

Comment: I have found the solution here: https://blog.vandenbrand.org/2015/06/25/creating-a-custom-doctrine-dbal-type-the-right-way/ . You have to add this text to the column comment: (DC2Type:CarbonDateTime) where CarbonDateTime is the name of the custom DBAL type you have defined. I have opened a new isuue in DBAL library in GutHub: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2506

Comment: @josecelano Issues got migrated to gihub. New URL: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/1137